# Single Front Controller for Multiple .Net MVC Web Projects in same Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, front-controller

I have a solution that contains two web projects (one Admin and one Public) as well as a number of class libraries. I have a front controller placed in the Admin project that gets invoked for every web request. My problem is that none of the controllers I create in the public project can be seen by the front controller in the admin project. How can I use the same front controller for both projects? Summary:

Admin
 -> Controllers
    - Front Controller
    - Other Admin controllers

Public
 -> Controllers
    - Public controllers (front controller doesn't "see" these controllers because they reside in another project).

Thanks for your help.